# DataTable Pagination calls API Rest

Tags: jquery, ajax, rest, datatable, pagination

I implemented a REST Api which return a Pageable element converted in Json. I decided to load only 50 records with every call and I would like that the pagination of DataTable through an ajax call, could handle the recall to the API. 
Let's say: if I have a 500 record, and the number of row per page is 10, as soon as I call the API I would like to see "1 to 10 of 500" with the number of page from 1 till 50 (e.g. 1 2 3 ... 50); when I click next or a number of page higher than the actual pagination, I would like to call the API and reload the real data from the DB.

Comment: I would like You to google "*dataTables serverside example*" :)

Comment: Wow... very precious suggestion!! I didn't know Google yet!! Thank you :P

Comment: You are welcome. I knew you just needed to be pushed in the right direction.

Comment: You are right... Now everything has a sense! <3